# изменение цвета переменной типа String

Tags: java, android, строки, color

Я создал переход по нажатию на кнопку с одного активити на другое с помощью интента, при этом через метод putExtra я переношу информацию написанную пользователем в едит тексте первого активити во второе. но мне нужно изменить цвет написанного пользователем текста в первой активити во втором. через setTextColor у меня это сделать не выходит т.к  использую переменную типа String и весь мой код подчеркивает красным. не знаю что делать,уже неделю пытаюсь по всякому решить это проблему,облазил весь гугл,но ничего стоящего не нашел.

```
String name_1 = "";
String name_2 = "";

name_1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ego_imya");
name_2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ee_imya");

TextView names = (TextView)dialog_1.findViewById(R.id.textSImenami);
names.setText(name_1 + " и "+ name_2 + " очень любят друг друга и свою кошку Эссю " );
names.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black60));
```

вот код. нужно изменить цвет текста name_1 и name_2 на black,но при этом,чтобы текст остального текста оставался black60. В общем выделить два ключевых слова

Comment: Приложите свой код, пожалуйста. Тип переменной `String` никаким образом не может быть связан с цветом текстового поля при отображении пользователю. А если навести мышь на подчеркнутую красным строку, то AndroidStudio скажет Вам, в чем ошибка

Comment: Ну и какая конкретно строчка у Вас подчеркивается красным, что пишет AndroidStudio?

Comment: в данном коде никакая. но чтобы я не предпринял написать,любой код подчеркивался красным. в этом и суть вопроса,как мне изменить цвет? мои попытки успехом не увенчались

Comment: добавил ответ, не пользовался этой штукой давно, а студию открывать сейчас лень, так что могут быть опечатки. Не помню точно, можно ли выделять два отдельных участка именно так, как это сделал я. Проверьте, если не получится - постараюсь помочь. Если что-то будет непонятно - пишите в комментариях к моему ответу, я постараюсь объяснить.

Comment: заработало конечно,большое спасибо,но заметил следующее,что если слова одинаковы,или начинаются с одинакового символа,то цвет меняет только первая переменная. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вам тогда нужно найти все вхождения слова. Либо можно попробовать объединять сразу Spannable строки, не знаю, можно ли так, но по идее возможность должна быть

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог - отметьте его принятым, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать `SpannableString`, если Вы хотите выделять отдельные слова в тексте.

```
String str = name_1 + " и "+ name_2 + " очень любят друг друга и свою кошку Эссю "; //создаем строку

ForegroundColorSpan foregroundSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED); //тут Ваш цвет

SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(str); //создаем Spannable вариант нашей строки

int startIndex = str.indexOf(name_1);//находим индекс начала первого участка для выделения
int endIndex = startIndex + name_1.length();//находим индекс конца первого участка для выделения
spannableString.setSpan(foregroundSpan, startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //выделяем первый участок

//далее аналогичные действия для второго участка
int startIndex2 = str.indexOf(name_2);
int endIndex2 = startIndex + name_2.length();
spannableString.setSpan(foregroundSpan, startIndex2, endIndex2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(spannableString);
```